# Mapbox GL JS custom symbol layer not visible when using external vector tiles

Tags: layers, mapbox-gl-js

I've been using `mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9` as the map style and adding a custom symbol layer for land parcel IDs. These show fine.

If I instead load with a different style `https://api.os.uk/maps/vector/v1/vts/resources/styles?key=xxx` then the symbol layer isn't visible.

However any line layers I've added are still visible, just not the symbol one.

I've checked the layer order and all seems fine, my symbol layer is the last in the list:

`console.log(this.map.getStyle().layers)`

[image]

Here you can see the symbol layer isn't visible with the OS Map Style:

[image]

However with mapbox's satellite view it is visible:

[image]

This is the layer:

```
       map.addLayer({
          id: 'ParcelLabels',
          type: 'symbol',
          source: 'ParcelsSource',
          layout: {
            'text-field': ['get', 'parcelId'],
            'text-size': 15,
            'text-letter-spacing': 0.05,
            'text-allow-overlap': true,  <-- added to try get it to appear
            'text-ignore-placement': true, <-- added to try get it to appear
          },
          paint: {
            'text-color': '#fff',
            'text-halo-color': '#000',
            'text-halo-width': 2
          }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the style you are loading has `glyphs` that match your defined font stack.

Try changing `text-font` layout property.

If it's not set, than the default is `[Open Sans Regular","Arial Unicode MS Regular"]` as per the [documentation](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/layers/#layout-symbol-text-font).

If both those fonts aren't available in the glyphs url your style has, than you are likely getting errors in the network tab of the developer tools you have been ignoring.

Comment: Thanks but there are no errors in the developer tools which I am using regularly, however, upon changing the icon to a cat (like the documentation), it works!  Thank you